# Storing a value for each ComboBox item

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In lack of a `Value` property I planned to use Classes for storing `Text` and `Value` properties for my `ComboBox` items. So far I've succeeded.

Here is my class:

```
Public Class clCombobox
Public cname As String
Public cvalue As Integer

    Public Property Display() As String
    Get
        Return Me.cname
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me.cname = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Value() As String
    Get
        Return Me.cvalue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me.cvalue = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String)
    cname = name
    cvalue = value
End Sub

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return cname
End Function
End Class
```

Data is being added to the `ComboBox` like this:

```
cmbComboxBox.Items.Add(New clCombobox("Text", 1))
```

It seems like this works so far. But how do I get data back. Like if I want the value of the selected `CheckBox` item?

I tried using:

```
CType(cmbCombobox.SelectedItem, clCombobox).Value()
```

Did not work.

Comment: What doesn't work about `CType(cmbCombobox.SelectedItem, clComboboks).Value()`? You realise it says clCombobo **ks** where it should be clCombobo **x**?

Comment: Yes, my bad. See my answer to you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx), use the [SelectedItem property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) to retrieve the object that you stored in it.

Code to retrieve value you want:

```
Dim selectedItem as clCombobox = CType(cmbComboBox.SelectedItem, clCombobox)
Dim value As Integer = selectedItem.cvalue
```

Comment: @user880980 yes it was, my bad. Have been coding in C# all day, hence the mistake. See my edit ;)

Comment: Thanks. No errors in the code, but when I run it I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on the second line of that code.

Comment: @user880980 Could you debug to see what `selectedItem` is? That is most likely your problem.

Comment: @user880980 Debug to see whether `cmbComboBox.SelectedItem` is `nothing` and if it isn't, tell me what is in there?

Comment: Well, your example works, but somehow it scrolls to index -1 (blank) every first time I make a selection after loading. Maybe something wrong somewhere else in the code. Apart from this, it works flawlessly. So thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user880980 You're welcome. Good luck figuring it out though!